# drupal course module adding payment object

Tags: ubercart

Please Somebody help me. I have spent almost a week working on this functionality but haven't got any success yet.
I have a Learning management system in drupal7 using the course 7.1 beta2 module, the LMS has courses in it. The requirement is to have the user buy the courses in-order to take the course but I am not able to configure it. Please can any body show me a way on how to configure the payment object so that the user will have to buy before even starting the course. I need a step-wise solution on this

Thanks in advance

Comment: The course module allows any content-type to be used as an e-learning course. From the question tagged, i think you installed ubercart. If so you can choose your course content type as product, provide price and configure a payment gateway in ubercart configuration

Comment: Thanks Anoop for your prompt reply. I have been doing that but I dont know what i am missing. Would you please elaborate your solution in a little detail. let me tell what I have been doing
1) I create a new course instance.
2) I created a new product with all the details in it.
3) I added a new course object course payment with reference to the product node.
4) saved the course and when i start taking the course it does not leads me to a payment page nor does it show any product information.

Thanks again

Comment: You should go through some ubercart docs http://www.ubercart.org/docs/user/30436/ubercart_3x

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution on the Course issue queue:

https://drupal.org/comment/7477856#comment-7477856

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.